# Invocable Method - how do you return a value from an invocable with no input parameters?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

Normally, with an invocable method, you'd do something to the effect of:

```
public static List<Output> invoke(List<Input> inputs) {
    List<Output> outputs = new List<Output>();
    for (Input i: inputs) {
        Output next = /*something based on Input i*/
        outputs.add(next);
    }
    return outputs;
}
```

Crucially, this also means the expected size of the `outputs` list is immediately available, as it matches the input.

But what if there's an expected output, but no expected input? Code like

```
public static List<Output> invoke() {
    List<Output> outputs = new List<Output>();
    //code
    return outputs;
}
```

Is there a way to know how big to make the `outputs` list?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you are asking for any Flow Interview [that might be bulkified](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm)

> For a correct bulkification implementation, the Inputs and Outputs should match on both the size and the order. For example, the i-th output entry should correspond to the i-th Input entry. This is required for data correctness when your action is in bulkified execution. For example, when apex action is used in a record trigger flow.

Thus, there must be an input argument for invocable Apex called by

- Record-triggered flows
- Schedule-triggered flows
- Auto-launched flows
- REST API access

as all of these can be bulkifed (there are other use cases of Flow Distribution that I did not consider like Next Best Actions, etc.)

The doc states that an invocable method can have at most one argument; implying that for Screen Flows you might be able to get away with returning a list of size 1 - I did not test this.

More likely, I suspect that you use a no-argument invocable Apex to do something and return nothing (`void`).

Personally, I'd adhere to best practice and always define matching arrays of inputs and outputs.

```
public static List<Output> invoke(List<String> inputs) { ..}
```

and just ignore the `inputs`

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd test this. Here is my code:

```
public class TestInvokable {
  @InvocableMethod
  public static String[] getData(String[] inputs){
    return new String[] {'updated!'};
  }
}
```

The flow:
The update in the flow (case updating contact department based on matching contact id)

[image: flow showing apex execution then record update]

In the developer console, execute this:

```
Case[] cases = [SELECT Id, Subject FROM Case WHERE ContactId != 
NULL AND Contact.Department = NULL LIMIT 10];
update cases;
cases = [SELECT Contact.Department FROM Case WHERE Id IN :cases];
System.debug(JSON.serialize(cases));
```

---

**The Results:**

```
FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR The number of results does not match the number of interviews that were executed in a single bulk execution request.
```

If you invoke a flow that has mismatched input and output, you get an error if you submit multiple records at a time. This could and will happen frequently, so don't do it, unless you want your flows to fail in hard to debug ways.

And to answer the question about size of outputs, you have to send something. Anything really. Just send `{!GlobalConstant.True}` or something. Then count the list size for your return list size.

ie:

```
  String resultList = new String[]{};
  for (String inputs : inputs){
    resultList.add('hi mum');
  }
  return resultList
```